# Bash Doesn't Support Floating Point Operations — But Why Can I Use BC?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, floating-point, bc

I read from a passage that

> Unlike most programming languages, BASH does not have builtin floating
>   point math (it does have builtin integer math, however).

However, I can still do

```
echo "5.0>5.9" | bc -l
0

echo "5.0+5.9" | bc -l
10.9
```

These are floating point numbers; why does `bc` still work in these situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Unix utility `bc` is not part of `Bash`.  The `echo` produces characters on its standard output; `bc` takes its standard input and performs math operations.  All that  `bash` is doing in this case is stringing together the standard output to standard input implied by the `|` operator.

Answer (score 3):

The expressions `5.0>5.9` and `5.0+5.9` are sent to `bc`, which is a stand-alone program.